# Show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^z}$ converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, exponential-function

I want to show that $\large\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^z}$ converges absolutely for $\Re(z) > 1$, so

I want to show that $\large\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |\frac{1}{n^z}|$ converges, or

$\large\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |\frac{1}{\exp(z\log n)}|$

or

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |\exp(-z\log n)|$

any ideas?

Comment: What is $\lvert e^{x+iy}\rvert$?

Comment: $n^{-s}=n^{-\Re(s)} e^{-i\Im(s)\ln n}$ so the imaginary part does not affect to the absolute convergence.

Comment: @DanielFischer it is $|e^x| |e^{iy}|$.

Comment: @tetori can you explain why the imaginary part does not affect the absolute convergence?

Comment: @terribleatmath Because $|e^{it}|=1$ if $t$ is real.

Comment: @tetori thank you. I don't actually know why that is true, but that is cool. if you'd like to explain feel free, i am always up for learning :)

Comment: @DanielFischer I now have only that

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{exp(x)}$ , what can I do with this?

Comment: @tetori did I do something incorrectly if I just have a series like this, involving no n termms?

$\large\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{exp(x)}$ ?

Comment: @terribleatmath $\sum_{k=1}^Ne^{-x}=Ne^{-x}$. 

But I don't know why you do a this question. You can take $x+iy=s\ln n$ and you can apply the fact $|e^it|=1$ if $t$ is real number...

Comment: actually I think I was wrong, it should be $exp(xlogn)$ not just $exp(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^z}$$
is the zeta function $\zeta(z)$.
Now, the *modulus* of a complex number $z = x + iy$ is defined by $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. So, in particular, $|e^{iy}| = |\cos y + i\sin y| = \sqrt{\cos^2 y + \sin^2 y} = 1$.

Using Riemann's notation $z = \sigma + it$ for a complex number, we see that:
$$|\zeta(z)| \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left|\frac{1}{n^z}\right| = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{|n^{\sigma + it}|} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{|n^\sigma||n^{it}|} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{|n^\sigma||e^{i t \log n}|} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{|n^\sigma|}.$$
Observe that we set $y = t \log n$ and used the fact that $|e^{iy}| = 1$.

Next, we see that for $\sigma \ne 0$,
$$\int_1^\infty x^{-\sigma} dx = \lim_{M \to \infty} \left[\frac{1}{1 - \sigma} x^{1 - \sigma}\right]_1^M.$$
However, $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{-\sigma} = 0$ and $x^{-\sigma}$ is decreasing, which means $\zeta(z)$ converges for $\sigma = \Re[z] > 1$ by the Cauchy Integral Test.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{|n^z|} = \frac{1}{n^x}$ where $z = x +iy$, now just observe that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^x}$ converges only if $x > 1$ by the integral test.